# Count per each group, where each has custom conditions

Tags: database, postgresql

I have an app where a user can create groups and then specify conditions for each group. Currently I store the conditions as type/field/value columns in a separate table, and I generate a `WHERE` clause from that (in my app's code). I could instead create DB views or functions.

Some examples of conditions that the user could choose (where ? is user defined):

- `field1 > ?`
- `field2 ILIKE '?%'`
- joins may be required (no harm if all the joins are always done)

Now I'd like to just get a `count(distinct id)` of matching rows for several of such groups (each group having different conditions). An individual row might match several groups, in which case it should count for all of them.

Is there a way to do this in a single query, perhaps using views (but not materialized views) or pl/pgSQL (checking each row if it matches the conditions, taking into account it could match conditions for multiple groups)? Would `CASE` work here perhaps? The fact each row might match multiple groups seems to be problematic. I can modify the DB schema if necessary.

In the specific case, all the groups will be matching rows from a specific subset of a table (i.e. WHERE user_id = X). So what I'd like is to go through all of those rows in one pass and determine for each one which groups it matches (may be multiple).

The best I was able to come up so far is generating queries for all the groups and then `UNION`-ing them together so I don't need several round-trips to the DB. Is there a more performant solution or is this the best I can do in this situation? Basically I want to avoid a N+1 query just to get the counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need [`filter` in aggregate expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES), a feature introduced in Postgres 9.4. Example:

```
drop table example;
create table example (id int, col1 text, col2 text, qty int);
insert into example values
(1, 'a', 'b', 1),
(2, 'a', 'a', 10),
(3, 'a', 'c', 11);

select
    count(distinct id) filter (where col1 ilike 'a%') cond1,
    count(distinct id) filter (where col2 = col1) cond2,
    count(distinct id) filter (where qty = any (array[1, 2, 3])) cond3
from
    example;

 cond1 | cond2 | cond3 
-------+-------+-------
     3 |     1 |     1
(1 row)
```

Comment: didn't test yet but this definitely seems like it should work for me, thanks!

Comment: Was this just added in Postgres 9.4? If yes could you update your answer to reflect this.

Comment: Postgres version, if not latest, [should be in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info).

Comment: I'm fine with either version, but I think it will be relevant information to other people reading this.